# Java read text file using java I/O imports, and summing certain integer columns?

Tags: java, text, io

I have to read in a text file that has multiple columns, the 1st column being state number, (01-50) the 2nd column being a name of a certain housing location, the 3rd column has the total population per town that the housing location is in, the 4th column is the number of possible housing capacity, the 5th column has the number of available housing from the previous column. The 6th and 7th columns have useless ID numbers and dates. Each state has multiple housing locations.

The goal is to create a new output, with 1 row for each state. The 1st column has to be the state number, 2nd has to be total population per state given each town population, the 3rd column has to be total number of possible housing capacity, the 4th column has to be the total availability, and the 5th column has to be the percentage of availability.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
import java.io.*;
public class housing
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String fileName="housingdata.txt";
        try
        {
            FileReader File = new FileReader(fileName);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(File);
            String line;

                while ((line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
           System.out.println("Error.");
        }
    }
```

}

As you can see, this code loads the textfile, but I am unsure how to begin doing operations per column as needed. I am a novice at Java. I appreciate any help you can give. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

At this point, when you have a line  , you start to split the line by some delimiter you have ,  getting array of column values. After that , you can do whatever you want .

UPDATE
 **1.** This is really dirty one, but you should get the logic
 **2.** You`ve started to talk about aggregation of data you extract , if you will go futher, you  better use some lightweight sql database solution. this will simplify things a lot.

```
...
HashMap<String,Integer> agregatedData = new HashMap<>();
...
{
 System.out.println(line);
 String[] splittedLine = line.split(",");  \\ Assume delimiter is coma

 System.out.println("State number : "+splittedLine[0]);
 System.out.println("Housing name : "+splittedLine[1]);
 System.out.println("Population : "+);

 if(agregatedData.containsKey(splittedLine[0])){
      //If we already have some population for this state, do summation
      int v = agregatedData.get(splittedLine[0]) ;
      agregatedData.put(splittedLine[0],Integer.parseInt(splittedLine[2]) + v);
      }else{
      //If there is no record with such  state code yet, add new one
      agregatedData.put(splittedLine[0],Integer.parseInt(splittedLine[2]));
      }

            }
```

Comment: Thanks, how would I say, add the populations for the housing populations in state 01?

Comment: thanks for the reply, I unfortunately cannot use a hashmap function. is there any alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Having already a line from your file you need to "parse" values from it.

Commonly there is a usage of a delimiter like comma (,) or semicolon (;)

You can split by delimiter:

```
String[] columns = line.split(",");
```

Then you can iterate over the array:

```
for(int i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
 System.out.println(columns[i]);
}
```

And start your operations in the for loop.

Comment: This line splitting between columns is a space, and sometime multiple spaces, how would this look?

Comment: Also how do I begin the operations? can you elaborate? @Stefan